Will a 0.37kW 0.5HP 1PH 180-240V 2.8A water pump work with a TP-Link P110 16A smart plug?
The water pump has mentioned these thing on it's label:

0.37kW
0.5HP
1PH
180-240v
2.8A

And the manual of TP-Link says only 1/6 HP Motor is supported.
Specifications:

Voltage: 220-230V~ 50/60Hz
Max Load: 16A General Use & Resistive, 1/6 HP Motor
Operating Temperature: 0 ºC – 40 ºC
Operating Humidity: 10% - 90%RH, Non-condensing
Socket-outlet: Combined socket-outlets of IS
1293:2019. Suitable for two-pin and three-pin plugs
in Annex B of IS 1293:2019.


is 0.5 equal or or less than 1/6?   ... this is basic arithmetic

but current is 2.8amp which is less than 16amps.

you said it yourself only 1/6 HP Motor is supported

Current start may be too high ...

Motor ratings are more restrictive since they are inductive loads. Your 1/2 HP motor will not work with the 1/6 HP max rating of the smart plug, even if the current rating is less. Use a 240V relay rated for the motor's HP.
